# Including 'wp-load.php' after another include() generates an error

Tags: ajax, wp-load.php

I know all the [downsides](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) of trying to include wp-load.php, but bear with me :)

I'm trying to create my own admin-ajax-like functionality, in a way that I can control whether or not I load the default WordPress environment, whether I load it with the `SHORTINIT` constant defined as true, and with granular control over each module of my plug-in, as required by the specific function being access via AJAX. The only way I can think of doing that is doing AJAX via a custom file, other than admin-ajax.php, and then including wp-load.php when desired.

I've actually used it successfully for months. I've named the file `bootstrap.php`, and it sits inside my plugin's 'includes' directory. Requiring `wp-load.php` from within `bootstrap.php` will load WP just fine.

Today I decided I needed more control, so I attempted to delay the request for `wp-load.php` for when I've loaded the files containing the AJAX functions. Those files are called within `bootstrap.php` with `include()`, but requiring `wp-load.php` within those files will generate the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: wpdb in .../wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 126
Fatal error: Call to a member function set_prefix() on a non-object in .../wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 126
```

The problem occurs within the loading of WP, so obviously the `require()` call points to the correct location of the `wp-load.php` file. Calling it from the file of the URL request works fine, but calling it after an `include()` breaks the entire thing... any ideas why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out it was a problem of variable scope. I discovered that `$wpdb` was loading fine, but was inaccessible outside of the function that generated it, so it kind of led me to the solution: the `includes()` I mention in the question are done inside a function, with local (not global) scope. I'm sure, then, that it would have been a problem for all WP global variables, but $wpdb was the first one to generate a fatal error.

I didn't mention I was loading wp-load.php from a function because I didn't really know it was important. So remember, kids: [don't include wp-load.php](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/), but if you do, **don't do it from inside a function**.

Answer (score 1):

A different way of fixing it:

```
function load_wp(){
    global $wpdb;
    include_once('wp-load.php');
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that's pretty clever :) I wish I had thought of that at the time...